# XML Schema How to Restrict element by minLength \ maxLength

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I've been trying to solve this issue for a few hours now, the problem is that my validation process doesn't really take into account anything I type inside the restriction.

This is my XSD:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/myxmltest">
    <xs:element name="Students_With_Preferences-xml">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Student-xml" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="District"/>
                            <xs:element name="Preferences">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="5"/>
                                        <xs:maxLength value="5"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Xml Sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Students_With_Preferences-xml xmlns="http://tempuri.org/myxmltest">                                 
    <Student-xml>
        <District>b</District>                              
        <Preferences>(sc1,20)|(sc2,15)</Preferences>        
    </Student-xml>
    <Student-xml>
        <District>d</District>
        <Preferences>(sc2,15)|(sc1,10)</Preferences>    
    </Student-xml>
</Students_With_Preferences-xml>
```

As you can see only element with length 5 is allowed, but when I run my code it allows any length.
Just to be clear, everything else is validate properly, just this annoying error.

I tried to fix this issue using the regex option but as u guessed its not working as well.

Validation Code(C#):

```
    private Boolean ValidateXML(HttpPostedFileBase file, string xsd_path)
    {
        bool errors = false;
        string filename = "";
        XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
        XmlDocument xml_doc = new XmlDocument();
        try
        {
            filename = file.FileName;
            schemas.Add("", xsd_path);
            xml_doc.Load(file.InputStream);
            foreach (XmlNode node in xml_doc.ChildNodes.Item(1).ChildNodes)
            {
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(node.OuterXml);
                doc.Validate(schemas, (o, e) =>
                {
                    ViewBag.msg = "Error validating - " + filename + " - " + e.Message;
                    errors = true;
                });
                if (errors) break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errors = true;
            string msg = "Error validating - " + filename + " - " + ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(msg);
        }
        if (!errors)
        {
            ViewBag.msg = filename + " was validated succesfully";
        }

        return !errors;
    }
```

I would really appreciate any help on how to fix this issue, Thanks!

Comment: Your length restriction works well. However, there are various other issues with the Xml documents (aside from the fact that the samples you present here are missing some closing tags and thus do not constitute complete samples): In your schema, there is a `Schools-xml` element that contains `School-xml` elements, whereas in your instance document, you are using a `Students_With_Preferences-xml` element that contains `Student-xml` elements. In your schema, the innermost elements are named `Id` and `Preferences`, whereas they are `District` and `Preferences` in your instance document.

Comment: Lastly, to make your sample work on [this online validator](http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html), I had to add the namespace `http://tempuri.org/myxmltest`, which you use in your instance document, to the schema in the `targetNamespace` attribute, so the schema document is actually associated with that namespace, and also provide the schema document with an `xmlns="http://tempuri.org/myxmltest"` attribute to make sure any identifiers declared in the schema document are considered part of that namespace. After doing so, your length restriction works as desired.

Comment: Thanks for your input # O. R. Mapper, I fixed the post. guess that's what happens when u work on something too much.
btw I do know that online validators are showing the right result to my xsd + xml, this is why I suspect it has something to do with my ValidateXML fucntion which I also posted.